# Is MUI 32 bit compatible with 64 bit?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, 32-bit, language

I need to install Russian language user interface in 64 bit Windows Vista system. Can I use 32 bit MUI software here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Microsoft has competely separate language and localisation packs for 32 bit and 64 bit systems.

However [this](http://www.froggie.sk/lp64sp2.html) site may help you. I haven't used it, just googled about a bit, so I'd check it out first.

Hope this helps.